# Customized radio buttons not looking properly in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Here is the customized radio button http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/ZYKxc/7/

I need to know how to make the details button properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons are being included in your 'controlgroup'. to render the buttons independently remove

```
data-role="controlgroup"
```

from your fieldset tag

http://jsfiddle.net/ZYKxc/15/